# Using find -exec in systemd ExecStartPre

Tags: systemd, find, systemd-service

I think it's fairly obvious what I'm trying to do here

```
# Rename Log File
ExecStartPre=/bin/find /data/db/log/*.log -type f -exec mv {} {}.`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M"` \;
# gzip past log files (is post becuase might take a long time)
ExecStartPost=/bin/find /data/db/log/*.log.2* -type f -mtime +2 -exec gzip {} \;
# delete really old stuff
ExecStartPost=/bin/find /data/db/log/*.log.2*.gz -type f -mtime +90 -delete
```

these get "Executable path contains special characters, ignoring"

Any suggestions what I'd need to do to get these working?

Answer (score 0):

systemd does not expand glob patterns like `*.log`, and interprets several `%` prefixes as specifiers. It also parses `\` before some characters.
You therefore need to run the find command inside a shell, and escape `%` with `%%`, and `\`.

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/bin/find /data/db/log/*.log -type f -exec mv {} {}.`date +"%%Y%%m%%d-%%H%%M"` \\;'
```